# Data outputting to excel causes numbers to change

Tags: java, excel, io, apache-poi

i'm writing a program that calculates moments from a shape and writes the results to an excel spreadsheet, using the apache poi package

Anyway, i'm getting the correct figures its just when i write them to the spreadsheet, the figures mysteriously change, for example the program will produce a result like 8.092238721555691E-4, but in the spreadsheet its stored as 0.000809224....

To deepen the mystery some the figures are being stored correctly...

Has anyone any experience of something similar, or any suggestions?

Comment: The figures `8.092238721555691E-4` and `0.000809224` look equivalent; the first is pseudo-scientific notation for the second.

Comment: If you are going to do _anything_ with floating point numbers, in any context, you MUST read this: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are same: you can read `8.092238721555691E-4` as `8.092238721555691 * (10^-4)`